# MySQL update all rows to add time to timestamp gives: "Column 'start' cannot be null"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing a column named "start_date" which is a datetime and cannot be null. I want to add an hour to all datetimes in one single update query, but it gives me the error message `Column 'start_date' cannot be null`

I'm using MySQL 5.7.17 and the following query:

```
UPDATE tbl_event SET start_date = DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

It works fine when I'm doing it on one single row, but not when I want to change all. Am i missing something here?

Edit: Here is the create syntax for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_EVENT_CREATED_BY` (`created_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_EVENT_CREATED_BY` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=442 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Looks like you have null values in this column. Try to select all records where start_date is null

Comment: What @Jens said - and if you want to update those that are not null, just add `WHERE start_date is not NULL` to your query

Comment: I said in my question that the column is set to not null, so it doesn't contain any null values. All values in the column are valid datetimes.

Comment: What kind of constraints are on the table?

Comment: There is only a constraint for a foreign key. I updated the question with the create synax of the table.

Comment: Does it *really* say "Column '**start**' cannot be null"?

Comment: Strict mode: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80885

Comment: There are maybe some `0000-00-00 00:00:00` values in the column.

Comment: Try to find an example of a value which is making the statement fail with `SELECT start_date FROM tbl_event WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) IS NULL;` This could be happening validly: for example, if adding an hour would take the value over the acceptable range of values for a `datetime`.

Comment: Thank you GhostGambler and Matt Gibson. There was a `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in there which caused the problem. Your query found it.

Comment: I shall add an expanded version of my comment as an answer; it might help someone else in future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless something extremely odd is going on, I think the only thing that could cause your problem is if you have at least one (non-NULL) value in `start_date` where adding an hour to it could produce a NULL.

It's possible that a value exists that could push the result over the valid `datetime` range, for example; I think that would reproduce your problem in certain MySQL versions.

(As you've now made clear in the comments, and as suggested by GhostGambler, the values were old MySQL "zero dates" (`0000-00-00 00:00:00`) which exhibit some strange behaviour, including yielding a `NULL` from `DATE_ADD`.)

You can find the rows with values that are causing your problem with:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_event WHERE DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR) IS NULL;
```

...and then act from there to correct the data or the query depending on what you find.

Comment: I cannot conceive of why adding 1 hour to a non-null value would produce null as the output, but I guess that's mysql for you.

Comment: @Donnie It's because the `DATE_ADD` function will return `NULL` in cases where the operation doesn't really make sense, combined with the weird history of "zero dates" in MySQL, which were a "sort of null" value in the past. These days you wouldn't even be able to put the zero dates (`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`) in the table by default, as out of the box MySQL [has `NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) enabled. So, a quirk of history and old data, I'm guessing.